# Can I use adapters to mount Samyang lenses to my Nikon body?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, lens-adapter, used-equipment

I recently got two Samyang lenses at a second-hand store, so I don't have any boxes or documentation with them. The lenses I recently got are:

- Samyang AF lens 70-210mm 1:40-5.6, No. 846209
- Samyang AF lens 28-70mm 1:3-4.5, No. 627200

Are there lens mount adapters I can purchase for them so they fit my Nikon D7100? I don't know what their current lens mount is.

Comment: Samyang is a brand, not a mount. Which mount do your lenses have? It will say on the box and in the specifications manual.

Comment: I found them at a second hand store so no box or manual, I have a Nikon d7100 and the lenses match up to my camera body so I cannot lock them in to be able to use them

Comment: We cannot answer then. Adapters from some mounts to other mounts are not all physically possible.

Comment: Take a photo of the mount mechanism then [edit] your post to include it and someone might be able to tell you what it belongs to. Its probably Canon EF if it doesn't fit your Nikon but no way to know for sure without seeing it.

Comment: See also: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y

Answer (score 3):

If the lenses are not currently made to mount on Nikon DSLR bodies (i.e., Nikon F-mount), then **no, you probably cannot buy an adapter to use them on your Nikon body**.

The reason for this is that Nikon's F-mount has one of the largest [*flange focal distances*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) (also known as *registration distance*) for currently-available DSLR bodies on the market. I believe your Samyang lenses are available for the following mounts: Nikon F; Canon EF; Canon EF-S; Minolta/Sony A; Pentax K.

The Nikon F mount has a 46.5mm flange focal distance, larger than all of the other mounts listed above. So if your lenses are *not* F-mount ready, then they are *physically too long* to be used on Nikon bodies, and still be able to focus at infinity.

However, if the lenses were made for Nikon F-mount, then in terms of flange-focal distance, they could *in theory* be mounted on any of the mounts I listed above, or any other mount that has a flange focal distance of less than 46.5mm. In other words, Nikon F-mount system is the "universal lens *donor*", whereas something with a relatively tiny flange focal distance, like the Sony E-mount (18mm) or the Nikon Z-mount (16mm) would be almost a "universal lens *receiver*", in that most DSLR lenses can be adapted to mount on it.